# Re-size Row Height for Printing Dynamically

Tags: vba, excel, height, row

I am attempting to re-size row heights in order to fix printing gaps that appear when using auto re-size. example:

In excel:
[image: excel]

In Print Preview:

[image: Print Preview]

I've attempted a number of things in order to fix this with no luck.  An example of a manual fix to the issue:

In excel:

[image]

In Print Preview:

[image]

I cant fix this issue manually because the program this is for creates multiple workbooks with multiple cells that would have to all be changed when this issue occurs. It seems to occur with any cell that spans more than 3 rows, the issue still happens with both mono-spaced and regular fonts. I've tried using a character ratio to auto-fit height in vba but that didn't work and a few other ideas that fell short.

At this point im stumped. If you wish to recreate my scenario use 54pt column width, size 8 calibri font, word-wrap, auto-fit row height, and any filler text that is long enough.

Comment: Record a macro of you fixing it manually?

Comment: @findwindow I cant do that, I have hundreds of cells that need to be changed to different sizes all the macro would show me is changing the size from its current state to a new number that wouldn't be correct for every cell.

Comment: How do you fix it manually?  Just stretch the cell until it looks right in print preview?

Comment: are you doing any scaling when printing, or are you at 100%?

Comment: @gtwebb yes, I just shrunk the cell then went to print preview then back again till it looked correct. it seemed I needed to hide some amount of text on the excel view.

Comment: @oldugly I am using 100% scale i've tried others but had no effect.

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://superuser.com/a/515038) ?

Comment: @PeterT no as i said and as someone mentioned later in that post auto fit doesn't auto fit for print preview.  It only does it for the excel environment.